# Procedure or Function 'usp_SendEmails' expects parameter '@SchedId', which was not supplied

Tags: c#

Here’s my code behind:

```
protected void gvviewapproval_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString()))
        {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_SendEmails", cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        gvviewapproval.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the error message could be much more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a parameter named ‘@SchedId’ to the command object before executing the query.

i.e.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchedId", 3);
```